# Is Revelation 14:16 a pejorative?

Tags: revelation, eschatology, second-coming

> **[Revelation 14:15-16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation+14%3A15-16&version=KJV)** (KJV)
>
> <sup>**15**</sup> And another angel came out of the temple, crying with a loud voice to him that sat on the cloud, Thrust in thy sickle, and reap: for the time is come for thee to reap; for the harvest of the earth is ripe.
>   <sup>**16**</sup> And he that sat on the cloud thrust in his sickle on the earth; and the earth was reaped.

Is it possible that this is a good thing? The more I ponder it, reaping the harvest from a ripe earth sounds a lot like resurrection, rapture, gathering the bride, etc. Is there anything linguistically that would eliminate that possibility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a good thing, to the redeemed, but not to the unregenerate.

Mark 4:29

> But when the **fruit is brought forth**, immediately he putteth in the sickle, because the harvest is come.

Matthew 3:7-8

> ...“You brood of vipers, **who warned you to flee from the coming wrath**?
>   8 **Produce fruit** worthy of repentance...

Garden tools are symbolic tools for adding to the 'reign of the heavens', whereas weapons are symbolic for taking lives.

When 2 servants are commissioned with a devine errand into the earth, one with a bow, for example, the rider on the white horse in Revelation 6, and another with a sickle, as in Rev 14, a garden tool is often favourable to it's object, whereas a bow or a sword is bad news.

Consider what John says in;

> Luke 3:9 
>   And now also **the axe** is laid unto the root of the trees: every tree **therefore which bringeth not forth good fruit is hewn down**, and cast into the fire.

Such is the nature of these devices.

However it can be noted that some of these tools were both for weapons and for gardening as is the case for the axe and plenty more.
That's why the 'sharp sickle' is used on the 'vine of the earth', the grapes gathered, a figure of the ungodly 'gathered' out of the earth for wrath which John the Baptist indicated in Mathew 3:7.

Rev 14:18-19

> 18 And another angel came out from the altar, which had power over fire; and cried with a loud cry to him that had the sharp sickle, saying, Thrust in thy **sharp sickle**, and gather the clusters of the vine of the earth; for her grapes are fully ripe.
>   And the **angel thrust in his sickle into the earth**, and **gathered the vine of the earth,** and cast it into the great winepress of the wrath of God.

As to whether this is the rapture, on the back of the above, refer to:

> Math 13:38 
>   The **field is the world;** the good seed are the children of the kingdom; but the tares are the children of the wicked one

Matthew 13:41

> As the weeds are collected and burned in the fire, **so will it be at the end of the age.**
>   41 **The Son of Man will send out His angels**, and they will weed out of His kingdom every cause of sin and all who practice lawlessness.

This is the message in your quoted passage.